# Casting QByteArray to `long` outputs different result for same input

Tags: c++, qt, casting, qt5.6

**EDIT: Added full MCV example project.**

I have a strange problem where the same code and same input produce different output values.

The purpose of the code is to test a function that takes a value packed into 4 bytes, and unpack it into a single 32bit value. The expected value of `value1`, `value2` and `value3` in `test_unpack()` is 2018915346 (i.e. 0x78563412 because of little-endian unpacking). I got this method of unpacking from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36645547/797744). Below is an MCV example that you can easily build and see the problem for yourself. Note that if you comment out the body of `test1()` `test_unpack()` magically passes with the correct value.

**test_canserialcomm.cpp**

```
#include "test_canserialcomm.h"

#include <QtTest/QtTest>
#include <QByteArray>

long unpack() noexcept
{
    quint8 a_bytes[] = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78};
    QByteArray a = QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<char*>(a_bytes), 4);
    long value1 = *((long*)a.data());
    qDebug() <<  value1; // outputs "32651099317351442" (incorrect value)

    quint8 b_bytes[] = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78};
    QByteArray b = QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<char*>(b_bytes), 4);
    long value2 = *((long*)b.data());
    qDebug() << value2; // outputs "2018915346" (correct value)

    quint8 c_bytes[] = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78};
    QByteArray c = QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<char*>(c_bytes), 4);
    long value3 = *((long*)c.data());
    qDebug() << value3; // outputs "2018915346" (correct value)

    return value1;
}

void TestCanSerialComm::test1()
{
    QCOMPARE("aoeu", "aoeu"); // If you comment this line, the next test will pass, as expected.
}

void TestCanSerialComm::test_unpack()
{
    long expected {0x78563412};
    QCOMPARE(unpack(), expected);
}
```

**test_canserialcomm.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_CANSERIALCOMM_H
#define TEST_CANSERIALCOMM_H
#include <QtTest>

class TestCanSerialComm: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private slots:
    void test1();
    void test_unpack();
};
#endif // TEST_CANSERIALCOMM_H
```

**test_main.cpp**

```
#include <QtTest>
#include "test_canserialcomm.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    TestCanSerialComm testCanSerialComm;
    // Execute test-runner.
    return QTest::qExec(&testCanSerialComm, argc, argv); }
```

**tmp.pro**

```
QT += core \
    testlib
QT -= gui
CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = tmp
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = UnitTests

HEADERS += test_canserialcomm.h
SOURCES += test_canserialcomm.cpp \
    test_main.cpp
```

The output of `value1` in `test_unpack()` is wrong, despite the same code and same inputs. Strangely, if I remove the `qDebug()` calls and set a breakpoint, the debugger expression evaluator now shows that `value2` has the wrong value.

Any idea why this is happening? Or even how to troubleshoot this further?

**Additional Notes:** If I add a line `qDebug() << "garbage";` at the top of my function, all 3 values produced are correct.

Comment: look at the in-memory representations of the values, might give a clue (I don't have qt) - another thought: why not use a simple union to do this?

Comment: @slashmais Thanks for the tip. By "in-memory representations" do you mean the values for the vars I see in the debugger when I set a breakpoint? Those values are the same as `qDebug()` outputs. I'm not sure how I can use a union in this case.

Comment: I run your code and I get the same result for all three values.

Comment: Is there something else going on in your code? Can you post a MCV?

Comment: @Paraboloid87 Thanks to your comments I managed to isolate the problem even further, and have add an MCV example project  that reproduces the problem (I have tested it).

Comment: What size is `long` on your system?

Comment: So, what happens (ignoring alignment) when you attempt to alias a *4*-byte array as an 8-byte integral?

Comment: @ecatmur By God! What happens is that when I cast to an 8-byte, it reads 4 bytes past what the `QByteArray` actually contains. The lesson is to use fixed-width types, and `qint32` instead of `long` worked for me. If you post this answer I will accept it :) Thanks for your help

Comment: @ecatmur Is there anything I should prepare or be aware of in terms of data alignment when doing packing/unpacking?

Comment: by in-memory I mean you look at the memory-addresses containing the values / vars - may have helped you spot what ecatmur suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're compiling and running this program on a system where `long` is 8 bytes, but your `QByteArray` has only 4 bytes. That means that when you alias the array as a `long` (using `*((long*)a.data())`) you're reading 4 bytes past the end of the array, into uninitialized heap storage.

The fix is to use a type that is guaranteed to be 4 bytes in size, e.g. `std::int32_t`.

As an aside, using `*((long*)[...])` to alias memory is not guaranteed to work, primarily because of alignment issues but also (in the general case) because aliasing is only supported for types equivalent to `char` or a `signed` or `unsigned` variant. The safer technique is to use `memcpy`:

```
std::uint32_t value1;
assert(a.size() == sizeof(value1));
memcpy(&value1, a.data(), a.size());
```